# Ember model unnamed JSON variable

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to consume the following JSON response in Ember.

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "files": {
      "config.json": {
        "name": "config.json"
      },
      "style.css": {
        "name": "style.css"
      }
    },
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "url": "https://newexample.com",
    "files": {
      "settings.json": {
        "name": "settings.json"
      },
      "index.html": {
        "name": "index.html"
      }
    },
    "user": null
  }
]
```

Here's my first model "snippet":

```
export default Model.extend({
  url: attr('string'),
  files: hasMany('file')
});
```

And then my "file" model with which I created a hasMany Relationship to:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr()
});
```

index.js route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('snippet');
  }
});
```

I realise that this won't work since I'm not defining the first variable in "files". Though I can't figure out how one would do this since this variable is dependent on the filename.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: whats the name of the first model?

Comment: also share the route code

Comment: @MuhammadAteek Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement json `serializer` with `embeded record mixin` look at this link
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_embeddedrecordmixin

than you need to implement normalizefindAllresponse 
check this link for such methods 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html

so at the end your desired code is 
snippet.js serializer

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    files: { embedded: 'always' }
  },

 normalizeFindAllResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
  payload = {snippet: payload};
 // normalize your payload or json at here, it should be like as i explain below
payload.snippet
 return this.normalizeArrayResponse(...arguments);
  },
});
```

make sure that your json is in this format

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "files": [ 
      {
        "name": "config.json"
      },
   {
        "name": "style.css"
   }

     ],

]
```

read this document for your help.
http://thejsguy.com/2015/12/05/which-ember-data-serializer-should-i-use.html
basically you required to use serializer according to your needs and than normalize response from api.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for sending me in the correct direction.